# Linking error Boost libraries

Tags: c++, macos, boost, linker-errors

I built BOOST libraries with guides here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html
Then I wanted to compile following code:

```
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
  boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer t;

  for (long i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    std::sqrt(123.456L); // burn some time

  return 0;
}
```

I issued a following command in a terminal

```
$ c++ -o program main.cpp -I /Users/miszo97/Desktop/boost_1_65_0 -L /Users/miszo97/Desktop/boost_1_65_0/stage/lib
```

then it yielded

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer::auto_cpu_timer(short)", referenced from:
      _main in main-a716e4.o
  "boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer::~auto_cpu_timer()", referenced from:
      _main in main-a716e4.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I guess something went wrong with linking. Maybe separately-compiled Boost libraries weren't build correctly?

Answer (score 1):

There are *two* major options used for linking.

First there is the `-L` option which add a directory to search for libraries.

However, the linker don't know which libraries to *link* with automatically, it doesn't go though all possible libraries to find one that matches. And that's where the second option comes in: The `-l` (lower-case L) option which tells the linker to link with a specific library.

The libraries specified with `-l` are just the library names, not the full file names, and the linker uses the paths added with `-L` to find them.

In your case with the Boost timer library, the library name should be `boost_timer`, so you need to add the option `-lboost_timer` when linking.

Comment: I added this option and compiled fine. The problem is when I want to launch executable file called program. It tells me that it didn't load library libboost_timer.dylib [here is a photo](https://imgur.com/9Z6gjk6)